# how to import statement 'from kivy_garden.radialslider import RadialSlider'

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy_garden.radialslider import RadialSlider
```

I am unable to use this statement. Pycharm is underlining radialslider and RadialSlider in red.

Comment: What error message is shown when you hover the line? Do you have the library installed?

Answer (score 0):

it is probably due to the reason you install to your environment :

```
pip install kivy_garden
```

and you didn't install:

```
pip install kivy_garden.radialslider
```